# concatenate and print each array element with a suffix

Tags: perl

I have some files in a directory like:

```
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
```

I want to print them with new suffix:

```
#!/user/bin/perl

my @dir_list_initial = `ls *.txt | sed 's/.txt//g' `;
my $suffix = ".dat";

for (my $i=0; $i<=$#dir_list_initial; $i++){
print $dir_list_initial[$i] . $suffix;
}
```

I expect to print

```
A.dat
B.dat
C.dat
```

but it prints

```
.datA
.datB
.datC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try,

```
chomp(@dir_list_initial);
```

and later

```
print $dir_list_initial[$i] . "$suffix\n";
```

as every element of `@dir_list_initial` array has newline at the end of string.

Even better it would be to skip shell altogether, and use only perl,

```
my @dir_list_initial = map { s|\.txt||; $_ } glob("*.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing half of your program by running `ls`. Don't shell out when you can use builtin Perl mechanisms to do the same job The [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) can do everything you're doing with `ls` and you don't have to depend upon the `ls` command (what if this is Windows?).

Also, always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your program, it can save you a ton of grief by picking up common mistakes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

for my $file ( glob "*.txt" ) {
    chomp $file;
    $file =~ s/\.txt$/.dat/;
    say $file;
}
```

Note I'm using `s/.../.../` to substitute one suffix with another. You need to learn [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Your `s/.txt//` is not correct. The `.` can stand for any character, and you don't specify that `.txt` has to be on the end of the string. If my file was called `ftxtback.txt`, you'd change the file name to `.datback.txt` which is not what you want.

Comment: The elements of the list returned by `glob` don't need `chomp`. This is most simply done using a non-destructive substitution `use 5.014; say for map s/txt\z/dat/ir, glob '*.txt'`

Comment: Yes, you're right about `chomp` not being needed in this case. However, I'm just in the habit of using it anyway. Unlike the older `chop`, using `chomp` when it's not needed does no harm.

Comment: What? You `chomp` *every* string *everywhere*? That's a bit extravagant!

Comment: Only when I get input from outside like a read. I wasn't sure whether `glob` adds a `<NL>` to the end of strings or not. It's not something I use a lot. Just simply easier to chomp thank look it up.

Answer (score 1):

there's no need for calling `sed` here, perl can handle that well:

```
my @dir_list_initial = `ls *.txt`;
chomp @dir_list_initial;
my $suffix = ".dat";
foreach (@dir_list_inital){
  s/\.txt$/$suffix/; # this alters @dir_list_initial
  print "$_\n";
}
```

if you have a perl more recent than 5.14, you also can do this:

```
use 5.014;
my @dir_list_initial = `ls *.txt`;
chomp @dir_list_initial;
my $suffix = ".dat";
say s/\.txt$/$suffix/r foreach @dir_list_initial; # this doesn't alter the array.
```

and, as mpapec already has pointed out, it would be better to not involve the shell at all:

```
say s/\.txt$/.dat/r foreach <*txt>
```